# Typing tutor project

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which I'm trying to catch keyboard events from, but the form has buttons and so whenever I press the <kbd>Space</kbd> key one of the buttons thinks I'm pressing it down.

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{  
   if (btnclock.Text == "Start")
       e.Handled = false;
   else
   {
       i = Convert.ToInt16(rtb1.Text.IndexOf(e.KeyChar));

       if (i == 0)
       {
           rtb1.Text = rtb1.Text.Remove(0, 1);
       }
       else
            j++;

       textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString((j));
    }
}
```

How can I avoid this and keep capturing keystrokes on the form?

Comment: I didn't understand a single thing from your question. Please edit it to make it clear.

Comment: i can,t upload image that why maybe its hard to explain for me :(

Comment: "About Visual Studio" is not an acceptable question subject here, and your question is about a language, not "Visual Studio". Visual Studio is *not a language*, it's an IDE. Please edit your question to make it clear what you're asking about **code**, since it obviously has nothing to do with the operation of Visual Studio itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing the `space` key causes the button with focus to act as if it was clicked. Try explicitly setting the focus on the form upon displaying the form and also after a button click, so as to move focus away from the button after it carries out its action: `form1.Focus()`.

However as mentioned by Shani, it may be easier to have the user type inside a textbox. When a textbox has focus, most keystrokes (including `space`, but the `tab` key will shift focus to another control) can be caught with a handler to the textbox's `KeyPress` event, in a way very similar to the way you're capturing the form's `KeyPress` event.

Comment: thanks .problem solved ..`this.focus();` in the `KeyPress` event of form

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is to type inside a textbox, Add a textbox to your form, Name it (for the code, lets say - mTextBox).

and after pressing the "start" button, you could refer the focus to the text box :

```
mTextBox.Focus();
```

Your solution (register to Form.KeyPress) should work also, Try register to KeyDown.